# How can I get the original font name of some text using PDFKit?

Tags: cocoa, pdf, fonts

I wrote a script which parses information from PDF files and outputs it to HTML. It's written in Python, using `pdfminer`.

On some text segments, the font style can have semantic significance. For instance: bold, italic and color should trigger different behavior. `Pdfminer` provides scripts with the font name, but not the color, and it has a number of other issues; so I'm working on a Swift version of that program, using Apple's PDFKit, to extract the same features.

I now find that I have the opposite problem. While PDFKit makes it easy to retrieve color, retrieving the original font name seems to be non-obvious. `PDFSelection` objects have an `attributedString` property, but for fonts that are not installed on my computer, the `NSFont` object is Helvetica. Of course, the fonts in question are fairly expensive, and acquiring a copy just for this purpose would be poor form.

Short of dropping to `CGPDFContentStream` (which is *way* too big of a hammer for what I want to get), is there a way of getting the original font name? I know in advance what the fonts are going to be, can I use that to my advantage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDFKit seems to use the standard font lookup system and then falls back on some default, so this can be resolved by spoofing the font to ensure that PDFKit doesn't need to fall back. Inspecting the document, I was able to identify that it uses the following fonts (referenced with their PostScript name):

- "NeoSansIntel"
- "NeoSansIntelMedium"
- "NeoSansIntel,Italic"

I used a free font creation utility to create dummy fonts with these PostScript names, and I added them to my app bundle. I then used [`CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURLs`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretext/1499470-ctfontmanagerregisterfontsforurl?language=swift) to load these fonts (in the `.process` scope), and now PDFKit uses these fonts for attributed strings that need them.

Of course, the fonts are bogus and this is useless for rendering. However, it works perfectly for the purpose of identifying text that uses these font.